# How to use autocompletion from webpage

Tags: qt, autocomplete, qtwebkit, qnetworkreply

I want to write a GUI that uses the auto-completion of a website (here: "de.finance.yahoo.com").

As a result, I want a text field in my GUI where the user inputs a hint (e.g. "Ama"), and the webpage working invisibly in the background, extracting the auto-completion suggestions (e.g. "AMZN Amazon.com, Inc.") and suggesting them to the user in the GUI.

In other words, I want to "steal" the auto-completion features of the website without the website being visible to the user.

How can I extract the auto-completion suggestions from a QNetworkReply?

I wrote `downloadFinished(QNetworkReply *reply)` but I am not able to access the auto-completion suggestions.

Comment: Your question is missing an important aspect, which is how the original completion is achieved in the source content. What are you actually trying to get from that page? A javascript? A post/get reply? Are you using restful APIs to get json data? Or are you actually trying to "browse" the page hoping to get it from there and simulating strokes on it? Because, in that case, you're quite off course, and what you're trying to do is an extremely convoluted method to get something you could probably get from **real** APIs.